# Como mostrar menu que esta oculto usando una variable del Main

Tags: vue.js, vuex

tengo un componente en vue que es un menu a la derecha de la web y la idea es que al inicio este oculto y que se muestre cuando yo lo necesite. para ello en mi menu de la derecha puse:

```
 v-if="this.$EsVisibleMenuDerecha"
```

y en el archivo main.js lo declare de esta forma inicialmente

```
Vue.prototype.$EsVisibleMenuDerecha= false
```

Eso me funciona hasta ahi porque no se muestra el menu pues la variable tiene inicialmente false

Ahora desde otra parte de la aplicacion hice lo siguiente:

```
this.$EsVisibleMenuDerecha = true;
```

Pero no se muestra el menu

Comment: Por que estas usando variables globales en main.js?, ese tipo de variables deberian estar en tu layout o en App.vue. Cuando usas directivas en elementos del template no debes usar this, en la consola no tienes errores?, por que deberias.

Comment: Tambien puedes usar las variables dentro del componente que contiene el menu como opcion valida.